# HTML5 how to check if user has viewed the entire video?

Tags: html

HTML5 how to check if user has viewed the entire video? ie, without skipping through. It is straightforward on desktop based browsers, though iOS allows playback control even when you do not explicitly enable it. Therefore, simply listening to the 'ended' event is not accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in iOS. I can only test in Chrome and Firefox:

Use the **seeked** event

```
vid.addEventListener("seeked", function() {

}, false);
```

Additionally, if you only want to detect the user seeking forward, keep track of the playback position by listening to the **timeupdate** event and reading the **currentTime** property.

[See this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vWWds/)